# Querying datetime columns for 'Now' minus a certain amount of time?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

Is there a way in TSQL to query for rows where a datetime column's value is "now minus (a certain amount of time)" to select a time range?

For example in MySQL I could build this predicate like:

```
(EndTime BETWEEN NOW() - INTERVAL 2 DAY AND NOW())
```

How can this be done in TSQL in SQL Server?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You would use the **[dateadd](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186819.aspx)** function, e.g.

```
where endtime between dateadd(day, -2, getdate()) and getdate()
```

Because the column `endtime` is not a function parameter, the query optimizer can use any indexes that might be defined on it (the definition of [sargable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/799584/what-makes-a-sql-statement-sargable/799616#799616)).

Answer (score 4):

If you are trying to subtract two days from today, you can do

```
DateAdd( d, -2, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)
```

[DATEADD (Transact-SQL)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186819.aspx)

Answer (score 3):

You can use the [datediff](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189794.aspx) function.

For example, to find things created within the last five minutes, you could execute

```
select *
from   Table t
where  datediff(minute, t.CreationDate, getutcdate()) <= 5
```

Comment: Although simple, it seems like this approach would not be able to take advantage of index information (if it existed). But RDBMS optimizations are PFM to me.

Comment: @pst - you are right, `datediff` isn't [sargable](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/799584/what-makes-a-sql-statement-sargable/799616#799616).  [Bobby D's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5477653/tsql-now-minus-a-certain-amount-of-time/5477688#5477688) is more appropriate.